# I've got strange characters from Open AI API response using Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, openai-api

I am using APi with node JS and model is text-davinci-003 and I am getting strange characters at the end of responses (example:  æ ê ¿) and some words are not gramatically corect, example below (polish language)
“tak¿e mo¿e byc skomplikowany dla osoby bez odpoiwedniego doswiadczenia. Warto skorzystaæ z uslug profesionalisty aby uniknac problemow i míec pewnosæ”
Where it should be:
“także może być skomplikowany dla osoby bez odpowiedniego doświadczenia. Warto skorzystać z usług profesjonalisty aby uniknąć problemów i mieć pewność”

Below I listed you my createCompletion function

```
.createCompletion({
          model: "text-davinci-003",
          prompt: prompt,
          temperature: 1,
          max_tokens: 2500,
          top_p: 0,
          frequency_penalty: headings ? 0.5 : 0.3,
          presence_penalty: headings ? 1 : 0.7,
        })
```

I've tried different prompts in open Ai

Comment: It would be great to see your request and response. Then it would be possible to reproduce the problem an comment on potential reasons.

Comment: Sounds like encoding issue